# StreamWriter won't flush to NetworkStream

Tags: .net, networkstream, streamwriter

Using a `StreamWriter` to write to a `NetworkStream`, and a `StreamReader` to read the response.  The app is sending commands and reading responses to a news server.

Simplified code (sans error handling, etc.):

```
tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(Name, Port);

networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
serverReader = new StreamReader(networkStream, Encoding.Default);
serverWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream, Encoding.ASCII) {
                     AutoFlush = true
                   };

// reads the server's response to the connect:  "200 news.newsserver.com"
// commenting out these lines doesn't solve the problem
while (serverReader.Peek() > -1) {
    serverReader.ReadLine();
}

serverWriter.WriteLine("authinfo user username");

// expect response "381 more authentication required", but code just blocks
string response = serverReader.ReadLine();
```

The code blocks at that last line, presumably waiting for the network stream to send a response.

I can avoid hanging the app by setting a timeout loop using `serverReader.Peek()`, but I will always timeout; I never get a response.

If I telnet to the server and port directly and enter the commands, I get an immediate response.

If I call `serverWriter.Flush()` explicitly, instead of using the `AutoFlush` property, I still block and never get a response.

Any ideas why I'm not getting a response to the server using this approach?

Thanks!

## Resolved:

The above code *does* work for me, so I went back and built upon that code to the code that wouldn't work.

In the code that hangs, I was still using the timeout loop with serverReader.Peek(). Peek() always returns -1, even though there is data in the buffer to read!! Replacing the Peek() loop with a blocking call to ReadLine() solves my problem.

I put the timeout loop in originally because the app is multi-threaded, and I didn't want to block. I will have to revisit this issue and see how I can resolve the thread timing without using Peek().

Thanks all, good answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code *does* work for me, so I went back and built upon that code to the code that wouldn't work.

In the code that hangs, I was still using the timeout loop with serverReader.Peek(). Peek() always returns -1, even though there is data in the buffer to read!! Replacing the Peek() loop with a blocking call to ReadLine() solves my problem.

I put the timeout loop in originally because the app is multi-threaded, and I didn't want to block. I will have to revisit this issue and see how I can resolve the thread timing without using Peek().

Thanks all, good answers!

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that it's the `StreamWriter` that's the problem... but there's a simple way to find out. Download [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) and see what's *actually* coming and going on the network. That's by far the simplest way of finding out what's going on.

Comment: That's a good idea, WireShark is an excellent program, though I never thought to use it in a case like this.  I will file that away for future use.

Answer (score 2):

Try "authinfo user username\r\n". The RFC says NNTP command lines must be terminated by a CR-LF.

Comment: He's calling WriteLine() - which will use \r\n on Windows. If this is under Mono it's a different matter though...

Comment: Yeah, not under Mono, but I tried it anyway, same result.  Tried the equivalent (sending a blank command) under the telnet prompt... the news reader ignored the blank command.  Good to know, if I wanted to port to Mono I could add the extra lines in without an issue.

Comment: True, but TCPClient.GetStream() returns a NetworkStream, and I didn't think NetworkStream had a WriteLine method. (not sure it makes sense except for SMTP, NNTP, etc.) So, even if it lets you call the method, I'm not sure I trust it. I did an NNTP client years ago, and I remember explicitly adding the cr/lf. I do not remember whether I used NetworkStream, though.

Comment: @R Ubben: He's not calling it on the stream - he's calling it on the StreamWriter.