# BsonBinaryReader with NetworkStream

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there any possibility for making `BsonBinaryReader` accept a nonseekable stream e.g. NetworkStream?

So I don't have to save all the data persistently and afterward start parsing it via `BsonBinaryReader` but can instead happen on the fly?

Example:

```
var response = new NetworkStream(MAGIC);
var reader = new BsonBinaryReader(response)

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    if (reader.GotEnoughData())
    {
        var bson = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `BufferedStream` with buffer of sufficient size?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Hmm, thanks for the input. Tried it, and I still get a 'The stream does not support seeking.' exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036366/1435802 with a 16MB *(Max BSON document size)* buffer as input to the `BsonBinaryReader`.

For be able to read until *end of stream* i used the following:

```
public static Task WhileNotEndOfStreamAsync(this Stream stream, Action action, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        try
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                action();
            }
        }
        catch (EndOfStreamException)
        {
            // Swallow the 'EndOfStream' Exception
        }
    }, token);
}
```

To read the data until EOS:

```
using (var response = new ReadSeekableStream(networkStream))
using (var reader = new BsonBinaryReader(response))
{
    await response.WhileNotEndOfStreamAsync(() =>
    {
        var bson = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(reader);
    }, token);
}
```