# Wrap forward-only read-only Stream into seekable Stream in .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, .net-standard

What is the easiest way to wrap a forward-only non-seekable source `Stream` (with `CanSeek` being `false`, e.g. an incoming network response) into a `Stream` that supports seeking, but does only read the same bytes from the source once?

Does .NET Standard (C#) offer any implementation of `Stream` which can be used for this or do I have to write this functionality by myself?
I can imagine an implementation of `Stream` which gets the source `Stream` at construction, reads from it and stores bytes that are read for the first time in a cache or buffer which is then used for each subsequent read of the same bytes.

I don't want to wait for the source `Stream` to be read completely before accessing the wrapped `Stream` (because it's very large). Therefore copying the source into a local buffer before accessing the buffer is not what I want.

Comment: So you want a thread/Task to read into a stream and update it, while another thread can access it and seek it, all while being thread safe?

Comment: "I don't want to wait for the source Stream to be read completely" leaves you with a problem. Is `StreamWrapper.Position=futurePos` a blocking call? What if the source stream has no `Length`, can you `Position` past the end? How will this work?

Comment: Is BufferedStream part of .NET Standard?

Comment: @TheGeneral It does not have to be multi-threaded. The wrapping `Stream` can as well just read from the source `Stream` if it has not yet stored the bytes in its cache. So...

Comment: @spender ... yes, I think the `StreamWrapper.Position` setter call should block and wait until the source `Stream` has read enough to determine if enough bytes are available.

Comment: Otherwise, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036366/14357) might get you there....